# Clone a div containing form inputs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have developed a form where a person is putting in a booking for a helicopter flight. As part of the form, I have a select element where they choose how many passengers are on the booking. I had a div on the page which I used JavaScript to clone as many times as selected from the select option. Here's the problem - every time I clone the div and submit the form, it only displays the user inputs from the last cloned div. I have used "[ ]" on the end of each of the input names, but still no avail. I believe the issues may be because the div (and then the inputs of the form in that div) are being cloned client-side instead of server-side. I have been searching forums and tutorials for weeks to try and find a solution, but again, no avail.

```
<tr><td class="form_label">Passengers</td><td valign="middle">
<select id="numpass" name="numpass" class="form_e"/>
<option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  </select>
</td></tr>

<div id="passenger" class="passenger">
<div class="form_head">Passenger [] - Details</div>
<br />
<table width="100%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="4">

<tr>
<td class="form_label">First Name:&nbsp;<input type="text" name="cust_fname[]" class="form_f" required="required"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Last Name:&nbsp;<input type="text" name="cust_lname[]" class="form_f" required="required"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Weight (kg):&nbsp;<input type="text" name="cust_kg[]" class="form_a" required="required"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="form_label">Phone:&nbsp;<input type="text" name="cust_phone[]" class="form_g" required="required"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Email:&nbsp;<input type="text" name="cust_email[]" class="form_d" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<table width="100%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="4">
<tr><td class="form_label">Address:</td></tr>
<tr>
<td class="form_label">Number:&nbsp;<input type="text" name="cust_addr_num[]" class="form_a" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Street:&nbsp;<input type="text" name="cust_addr_street[]" class="form_b" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Suburb/Town:&nbsp;<input type="text" name="cust_addr_sub[]" class="form_f" /></td></tr>
<tr><td class="form_label">State:&nbsp;<input type="text" name="cust_addr_state[]" class="form_b" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Postcode:&nbsp;<input type="text" name="cust_addr_post[]" class="form_a" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Country:&nbsp;<select class="form_c" name="cust_addr_country[]">
<option value="">--- Select Country ---</option>
<option value="Australia">Australia</option></select></td></tr></table>
</td></tr></table>
</div>
<div id="repeat" class="repeat"></div>
```

JS

```
function cpyDIV(val){
    $("#repeat").empty();

    for (var i = 0; i < val -1; i++){
        var $clone = $("#passenger").clone();
        $clone[0].id += i;
        $clone.appendTo("#repeat");
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to supply code that demonstrates your problem, or you'll just get downvoted and this will get closed.

Comment: Sorry, was on iPad, just adding the code now

Comment: No worries - I'm not mad bro :p  Just advising you so you actually get what you need :)

Comment: I think you'd get more responses if you could simplify and extract the problem code part, instead of just dumping the whole code here. Also, cloning on the client side is perfectly fine.

Comment: Edited and shortened

Comment: how is this form submitted i dont see any `<form></form>` ?

Comment: @andrew - I've cut the code down as it was massive before. It is submitted to another PHP file via POST

Comment: What do you see in the browser network tab (f12) when you submit the form? you should see `cust_fname[]=James,cust_fname[]=Fred,cust_fname[]=Ron` etc

Comment: no, only see `cust_fname[]=Ron`

Comment: so it sounds like the inputs are not being cloned properly, are you using javascript? can you post the js?

Comment: @andrew - Posted above

Comment: A simple js mockup I made on jsfiddle seems to be okay http://jsfiddle.net/q47Lftpa/ - admittedly, it's not php, but the javascript is what I was looking at

Comment: @iamserious - thanks, but is there any way of having the number of passengers input as a select element that clones based on a "change" function?

Comment: sure, it's the same concept.. http://jsfiddle.net/q47Lftpa/1/
also, like @andrew suggested, the post request headers should contain all values, else something is wrong with the html itself

Comment: Things I would check are: make sure your form includes everything, check html (with inspect element) to make sure the structure of new elements are correct / makes sense. Check for id of everything to make sure it is what you expect

Comment: @iamserious - still coming to the same result